# Pysimplegui everything transparent except 1 element

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysimplegui

How to make **only** one Text element not transparent?

As transparent app I use **sg.Window** option **alpha_channel=0.1**, but
one text element I need to make better visible. It is possible with Pysimplegui? Maybe somehow with canvas or second Window?

App to test with:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import time

layout = [[sg.Text('', key='text'), sg.Button('Btn')]]

window = sg.Window('Sample window', layout,
               keep_on_top=True,
               auto_size_buttons=False,
               grab_anywhere=True,
               no_titlebar=False,
               return_keyboard_events=False,
               alpha_channel=0.65,
               use_default_focus=False,
               finalize=True
            )   

while True:      
    event, values = window.read(timeout=1000)
    window['text'].update('need better visability here ' + str(round(time.time()))) # this element should be not transparent
    if event == 'Btn':      
        print('test') 
    elif event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break
```

Comment: What do you mean by not transparent?

Comment: Generally, no.  In such a case, the alpha is an attribute of the window as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use multi-window for it

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import time

def popup(location):

    message = 'need better visability here ' + str(round(time.time()))
    layout = [[sg.Text(message,size=50, enable_events=True, key='TIME')]]
    window = sg.Window('Message', layout, no_titlebar=True, modal=True, location=location)

    while True:
        event, values = window.read(timeout=100)
        if event == sg.TIMEOUT_EVENT:
            window['TIME'].update('need better visability here ' + str(round(time.time())))
        else:
            break
    window.close()

message = 'need better visability here ' + str(round(time.time()))
layout = [
    [sg.Text(message, size=50, key='TIME')],
    [sg.Button('Start', expand_x=True), sg.Button('Exit')],
]
window = sg.Window('Sample window', layout, no_titlebar=True, finalize=True, grab_anywhere=True,)

while True:
    event, values = window.read(timeout=1000)
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break
    elif event == 'Start':
        window.set_alpha(0.1)
        location = window.current_location(more_accurate=True)
        popup(location)
        window.set_alpha(1.0)
    elif event == sg.TIMEOUT_EVENT:
        window['TIME'].update('need better visability here ' + str(round(time.time())))
window.close()
```